# Assigning object address to a pointer is not working outside main

Tags: c++, pointers

This code shows compilation error: ‘head’ does not name a type.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node{
         int val;
         Node *next;
};
Node *head;
Node a;
head=&a;
int main()
{
}
```

However this one compiles fine.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node{
        int val;
        Node *next;
};
int main()
{
Node *head;
Node a;
head=&a;
}
```

Is there something I'm missing. I checked but declaring a global object or pointer doesn't seem to be illegal. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment statement cannot exist outside a function body. You can convert the global version to initialization.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do assignation (`head=&a;`) at global scope.

You could do initialization though:

```
Node a;
Node *head = &a;
```